# preciso abrir a porta COM3 do meu Bluetooth pelo xamarin

Tags: xamarin

Estou com um projeto Mobile e preciso abrir a porta COM3 do meu Bluetooth pelo xamarin, alguém sabe alguma forma para mim fazer isso ?

Comment: Xamarin nativo ou forms? Qual plataforma (Android, Windows Phone, Ios)?

Comment: Forms. e na plataforma Android